# Internet wallaper

Tags: desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 xfce. When I am connected to the Internet it downloads and sets nice wallpapers.

1. Where are they stored, as in their directory, so that i can use them later on while offline
2. Is there a pre-installed background application in ubuntu xfce which automatically downloads and sets wallpapers (like what ubuntu-tweak) does

Comment: It may depends on *what* is downloading them.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded your pictures using an internet navigator, such as mozilla firefox or chromium, you can access the files you downloaded by clicking the 'tools' tab on top of your screen, then 'downloads'. You should see the pictures you downloaded, and then by rightclicking them, and choosing 'open containing folder', it'll open the folder containing your files. I hope that's what you were seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive what you are looking for is the [Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr Community Wallpapers.](http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/03/heres-11-community-wallpapers-chosen-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr.html) These are located in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`

As seen here:

```
$ ls /usr/share/backgrounds/
Backyard_Mushrooms_by_Kurt_Zitzelman.jpg  Jelly_Fish_by_RaDu_GaLaN.jpg
Beach_by_Renato_Giordanelli.jpg           Mono_Lake_by_Angela_Henderson.jpg
Berries_by_Tom_Kijas.jpg                  Partitura_by_Vincijun.jpg
contest                                   Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg
Foggy_Forest_by_Jake_Stewart.jpg          Sea_Fury_by_Ian_Worrall.jpg
Forever_by_Shady_S.jpg                    warty-final-ubuntu.png
Ibanez_Infinity_by_Jaco_Kok.jpg           Water_web_by_Tom_Kijas.jpg
```

Sources:

http://ubuntuportal.com/2014/03/heres-11-community-wallpapers-chosen-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr.html

An installed 14.04 system

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, in the root directory /tmp folder. It is saved as dailywallpaper and there is a small script written dailywallpaper.txt in the same folder

Comment: OK, can you explain how did you find it and more importantly . . . how did you install it ? if you weren't the one installing it, who did ?